# Anonymous web view configuration problem

Tags: configuration

I got this problem when trying to set the anonymous access for my local environment. i got this sp2010 running on my windows 7-64. and when i try to set the authentication providers. the button is unavailable. see attached img..

[alt text http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/1920/capturey.gif](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/1920/capturey.gif)

Thanks Before
N

Answer (score 1):

This post describes your exact problem and a solution. I figured it had something to dowith sharepoint running as a standalone installation and googled for "sharepoint standalone authentication providers":

> ok, you can even specify the Authentication providers from the following location. In Central Administration > Security > Under the General Security Section > Click On Specify Authentication Providers. Once on The Authentication Providers page choose the Web Application followed by clicking on the Default zone and setting the authentication as needed.

http://boardreader.com/thread/Granting_Anonymous_Access_in_a_Standalon_5h0hj__9bea650e-9948-4c5b-8054-67361b2a0cd0.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ran IE in as an administrator when connecting to the central admin.  Usually clicking on the central admin link from All Programs -> Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products does this automatically.

Comment: I've tried it before steve. no luck :) thanks though.